# How do I change the size of an Azure Cloud Service Worker Role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

We have a number of worker roles in Azure under a Cloud Service that are set to size Small by default. This doesn't seem to be configurable either in the Azure Portal or the Preview Portal, so how do I go about changing the size of the worker role without using PowerShell?

Comment: It is very frustrating that you can't change the instance size on a cloud service after it is deployed. I have wanted to do that several times myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in Visual Studio by right clicking on the role in question under the sub folder of "Roles", choosing properties and then there should be a drop down for VM size. Re-publish and the size change should be reflected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Services have the VM size located in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef`, which is part of the deployment package. This is why you are not finding the setting in the portal. You need to build and publish a new deployment package.

Since you don't want to do this with PowerShell, you'd need to make edits directly to your `csdef` file via an editor / IDE and then redeploy the package.